# Method in switchMap not being called again

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple subject in `MyComponent`:

```
private readonly selectedID = new Subject<number | null>();
```

that gets triggered through HTML input from another component:

```
@Input()
public set myID(value: number | null)
{
    this.selectedID.next(value);
}
```

Every time a new value is given in it, I want to invoke an HTTP call defined in `MyService` and display that object. To achieve this, I created a second observable that should map the `ID` to a new observable of an HTTP call:

```
public readonly myModel$: Observable<IMyObject>;
public isLoading = false;

constructor(private myHttpService: MyHttpService, private myAlertService: MyAlertService)
{
    this.myModel$ = this.selectedID.pipe(
        tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
        switchMap(id => id == null ? of(null) : this.myService.getMyModel(id)),
        catchError(e =>
        {
            this.myAlertService.handleError(e);
            return of(null);
        }),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = false));
}
```

With this `myModel$` observable defined, I pass it through the HTML template in an `async`-pipe that does the subscribing.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="myModel$ | async as m;">
  {{ m | json }}
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</ng-container>
```

But the problem now is, the first time when my `set myID` is called, it simply works (server throws an error and `alertService` handles it, but that's not part of my problem). But when a new ID is given, `myService.getMyModel` is not being called again which it should.

I tried different RxJS operators, also using the [decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) but to no avail. I think something else is wrong than a mere higher order operator but I cannot figure out exactly what.

I also logged the execution of the first `tap`:

```
tap((value) => { this.isLoading = true; console.log('hit', value); ),
```

This also gets called only once, i.e. for every new `ID` given, whether it be a real number or `null`, it simply does not get logged any more after the first time.

Comment: Not a solution, sorry, but a generic advice. `of(null)` will still emit a `null` so will force you to do null checks when trying to use your model. So instead of that, just return `EMPTY` (from `rxjs`), which will not emit anything, will just complete, which will keep the `switchMap` alive, and you can remove the `null` checks from many places. Yes, you need to move the `isLoading` logic closer to the `myService` call and only trigger loading when the `id` is present. To be able to help, please post your code _with_ the debug log statements. Also maybe put a log into the setter too.

Comment: Good thing to know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (server throws an error and alertService handles it, but that's not part of my problem)

That's exactly your problem :)

`catchError` doesn't magically restore the observable. The parent observable has thrown an error, it dies, and `catchError` lets you stop the propagation of that error, handle it how you want and return another observable to be consumed by the ones below.

Your `catchError` returns `of(null)`, which means observers will receive `null` followed by `[complete]`. The subscription is closed and nothing else will happen.

You have an easy solution though: Move `catchError` inside the `switchMap`. This way, the observable that completes will be the one inside `switchMap`, and the outer subscription won't close:

```
constructor(private myHttpService: MyHttpService, private myAlertService: MyAlertService)
{
    this.myModel$ = this.selectedID.pipe(
        tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
        switchMap(id => id == null ? of(null) : this.myService.getMyModel(id).pipe(
            catchError(e => {
                this.myAlertService.handleError(e);
                return of(null);
            })
        )),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = false));
}
```